# Javascript:alert('...') - Error: uncaught exception: ReferenceError: alert is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, alert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript alert not working in Firefox 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643414/javascript-alert-not-working-in-firefox-6)

I often execute Javascript code in the address bar (mostly for debugging and testing):
javascript:alert(some_function_with_interesting_return_value('blah'));
Or - more obvious:
javascript:alert('interesting value');

This doesn't seem to work anymore with Firefox 6:
Error: uncaught exception: ReferenceError: alert is not defined

How is it possible for alert() not to be defined ?

I've double-checked it with Firefox 5, Epiphany, Midori and Chromium - works fine.

Comment: Use the web console or scratchpad for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's maybe prevention,  because a lot of sites abused this.

> FYI, I'm probably going to split this bug into multiple, short and longer term fixes.
>
> Short term: disallow pasting of javascript: URLs into the URL bar
> Longer term: additionally require that bookmarklets be "whitelisted" in the Bookmark Manager before it can run JavaScript

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527530#c6

Comment: I see the point, it can be a (security) issue in some (rare) cases. Well, I could run my JS code from Scratchpad, but then I'd have to switch between two windows. Isn't there a way to temporarily allow JS in the location bar?

Comment: @basic6: I'm afraid it's not right now

Comment: I'm now using the command line of Firebug which works perfectly (actually better than the location bar).

Comment: @basic6: yes. I agree with you