# how to disabling javascript via URL address bar Like 4shared

Tags: javascript

Few weeks ago. 4shared now can not access javascript Via Address bar for security Reason to Injecting Countdown downloading. and if i typing javascript:alert('maho'); just return Undefined. and alert is not running.

are you know what 4shared use ?? :/

Comment: I went on 4Shared.com just now with Internet Explorer, and typed in `javascript:alert('hello')` in the address bar, and a message box popped up that said 'hello'.  It seems to be working with Internet Explorer.  Perhaps your browser is not allowing address bar JavaScript. Firefox 6 does not currently allow JavaScript to be executed via the address bar.  Like Jared says, this is dependent on the browser, not on the webpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert not working in Firefox 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643414/javascript-alert-not-working-in-firefox-6) ...

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a client-side language. Websites can't control what the web browser decides to do with a page once it's in the hands of the client.