# More robust way to get location.href in Javascript Bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

This is my current bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){ alert(location.href); })();
```

which seems to work fine, but for me, it doesn't work on youtube under chrome for some reason.. is there a more robust way to get the location.href?  Thanks.

Comment: Weird.  YouTube gives `about:blank` for some reason (on Chrome 16).

Comment: @Rocket Even weirder is that if you write `alert(location.href)` in debugging console - a proper address is shown...

Comment: Ok, it seems I figured this out. For some unknown reason bookmarklet's `Location` object contains the location from last request. And for even less known reason youtube's search box loads `about:blank` with after the main page is loaded (you can see it in developer console network tab).

Comment: So how would I get around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You may try

```
(function(window){window.alert(window.location.href)})(this);
```

which will make sure you're not using some custom `alert` function from the global namespace. But, there is no way prevent `window.alert` from being overwritten like so `window.alert = function () { console.log('Haha!'); };`.

The `location` object should be fail-proof, since the browser's internal setter method inhibits any shenanigans there (meaning that `window`'s `location` attribute is effectively write-protected, as is `window.location`'s `href` attribute)

**Edit:**
Looks like bookmarklets don't work in Firefox 6+ due to "social engineering bookmarklet attacks", and there's nothing you can do about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643466/27862
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527530

Comment: Looks like there's a [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inheritprincipal/) that restores the functionality