# get body tag value from website

Tags: javascript, html

I need to fetch body tag from the url which i open. I am using following code but it is not working. Please suggest.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
```

Thanks
Tanu

Comment: Insufficient information in this question to know what might be going on.  More of the relevant code and timing of calling this code is needed.

Answer (score 19):

Copy below code in url navigation bar. See, whole body content alerted.

```
javascript:(alert(document.body.innerHTML));
```

Its means you can get the body content by just body.innerHTML. you don't require to use getElementsByTagName.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working on FF 8.

Comment: It wouldn't do. [You can't run JS from the addressbar in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643414/javascript-alert-not-working-in-firefox-6)

Comment: yes. you are correct :) it works in IE,chrome. but, now you would have got at least the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try document.body.innerHTML?

Comment: ya i tried. It is working fine on chrome but not working on Firefox 8.Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Here is my simple test

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
MyFunction = function () {
    alert(document.body.innerHTML);
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="MyFunction();">

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

it's working on FF

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- The script runs after the document has loaded
- The script is running on the page that you want the body content from (which would **not** include [the address bar in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643414/javascript-alert-not-working-in-firefox-6)).

That that will work, although it is uglier than `document.body.innerHTML`.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working on FF 8.